# How to hide the colorbar and legend in plotly express bar graph?

Tags: python, plotly-express

I am creating a bar graph with something like this:

```
px.bar(df, x=x, y=y, color=c,
       title=params['title'], 
       hover_data=hover_data)
```

When `c != None` the graph produces either a legend or a colorbar. How can I remove either of them?

Answer (score 29):

For the legend, you can use either `fig.update_traces(showlegend=False)` or `fig.update(layout_showlegend=False)`.

For the colorbar, you can only use `fig.update(layout_coloraxis_showscale=False)`. On normal plotly figures, you could also do `fig.update_traces(marker_showscale=False)`, but it does not work for plotly express because of how [facetted traces need to share the same colorscale](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1858#issuecomment-549050563) .

Comment: ```fig.update_traces(marker_showscale=False)``` does work for me in Plotly express (I'm on using Plotly version 3.10.0)

Comment: Thanks @PolinaSklyarevsky, I have only been using plotly since v4 so I am not sure how it behaved before that.

Comment: In Plotly 5.14.0, fig.update(layout_coloraxis_showscale=False) works but fig.update_traces(marker_showscale=False) does not, at least for my use case.

Answer (score 27):

In [v5.1.0](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/releases/tag/v5.1.0), this works for me:

```
fig.update_coloraxes(showscale=False)
```

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Bar chart with gradient color bar on right side] | [image: Only bar chart] |

Comment: This is just a side note for anyone reaching this answer trying to remove the colorbar for a `go.Heatmap`, (i.e. using graph_objects, not plotly express).

You must first specify a coloraxis when making the Heatmap trace e.g. `go.Heatmap(..., coloraxis='coloraxis')`. 
Alternatively, `fig.update_traces(showscale=False)` will do the trick.

Answer (score 22):

This worked for me!

```
fig.update_traces(showscale=False)
```

Answer (score 13):

`fig.update_layout(coloraxis_showscale=False)` worked for me in `plotly 5.6.0`

Answer (score 5):

To hide the colorbar with plotly express using Plotly V4:

```
fig.update_traces(
    marker_coloraxis=None
)
```

Comment: This removed the continuous color completely ;-;

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the options already presented, `fig.update_layout(coloraxis_showscale=False)` works, too.

I find I often use `fit.update_layout()` already, so it's nice to be able to get rid of the colorbar in the same method call.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
```

worked for me in plotly version 5.15